# How to scan for patches using node and electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I am trying to build a custom service desk app using electron and node. I would like the app to be able to scan for patches and then push said patches but I am having a tough time doing so. I found the WUA (windows update agent) but i can not figure out if that is what i need and how to integrate it with javascript / node\

thanks

Comment: what have you tried doing?

Comment: nothing so far...this is farily new and i dont really know the direction to go....i am looking into powershell and a wsus server